# Creation of model in core data on the fly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

How can we create a model in core data on the fly? I.e getting the schema of database from somewhere and then creating a Core Data Object graph?

****QuesTion:****
Yes thats fine, agreed with all the advantages. But, can anybody can tell practically, what is the benefit of integrating Core Data into project instead of using SQL directly.

**1.** 
   - No need to write SQL boiler plate code [but need to learn Core Data Model (steep curve)]
**2.**
   - WE can undo and redo changes [but practically who needs it]
**3.**
   - we can migrate to another schema [that can be done by SQLite as well jus need to add another field into table]
**4.**
   - For say aggregation on some field in table,in Core Data we need to loop through Core Data Objects whereas in SQLite we need to first write SQLite Boiler Plate Code and then the basic aggregation SQL query,which is easy to write,only length of code will increase...But in case of Core Data (need to learn a lot).

So apart from reducing the length of Code,does it actually adds value to project? or in terms of
Memory Efficiency,Performance,etc..

**PS:** If anybody has actualy worked on Core Data(Model Creation On the Fly) , if possible share and gve pointers..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here's a good step-by-step tutorial from Apple, I hope it helps.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/03_createModel.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but still the answer seems to be incomplete..
In this Apple's Sample they are creating the entities i.e constructing the model graph by hard coding it..

What if we dont have the model inhand? (we dont know the entity name s while writing the code for constructing the model)

Hope the question is clear?

Comment: Well my succession in this case would be storing the entities names somewhere, from where you later can take the DB-scheme info to create your entities on the fly in obj-c.

Comment: I also think some XML-style format exists to describe the scheme of database, including entities (i.e. table) names. I never used it myself, but i hope Goolge knows better than me ;)

Comment: Also if anybody has experience on using Core Data..Can anybody please tell what is the real advantage in using core data..Since Core Data is build on top of SQLite only..apart frm adv like (Redo,Undo..etc)..Does Core Data has any real advantage over using SQlite directly?

Comment: CoreData provides you the ability to work with data as objects. SQLite (as well as XML or plain files) is only a physical representation of the storage. Here's a good point to start: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html

Comment: After above post,pl respond to edited Forum Question at top : After *QuesTion:* 

Thanks!!

Comment: hard to tell in short words what's the exact difference. To me it's really like comparing procedural and object-oriented programming. So in 'classic' SQL you operate with tables and rows and relatations between them. And in CoreData you work with objects which have all the data properties (in SQL they stored in fields\rows) plus required methods to operate them. I'm not saying that CoreData is for everyone and MUST be used in every project. Maybe you don't need it in your project, obj-c allows you to talk to SQL directly.